# get value from form select and then calculate value in an input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I am trying to calculate multiple values based on multiple selections from a  and then have the data add up and display in an  on the same form. I tried some jquery stuff but didn't really work at all. I've tried using some Javascript to do the calcultions but nothing seems to be happening.

Blade:

```
@extends('layout.layouts')

@section('content')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NCIC - Reports</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <h1>New Report</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="{{ 'storereport' }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Reporting Officer</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="profileid">SSN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profileid">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="report">Report</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="report" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectpicker">Select Offences</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="lawspicker" name="laws[]" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true" multiple>
    @foreach($laws as $law)
    <option value="{{ $law->name }} {{ $law->fine }} {{ $law->months }}">Offence: {{ $law->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="punishment">Punishment</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="punishment" name="punishment">
  </div>
  <hr style="background-color:white;">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  <a class="btn btn-info float-right" href="{{ route('reports') }}">Main menu</a>
</form>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    $("#lawspicker").keyup(function(){
      $("#punishment").val(parseFloat($("{{ $law->months }}").val()) + parseFloat($('{{ $law->fine }}').val()));
    })

    $("#lawspicker").change(function(){
      $("#punishment").val(parseInt($("#lawspicker").val());
    })

  </script>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: #353b48;
      color:white;
    }
  </style>
</html>


@endsection
```

To clarify, I want `{{ $law->months }}` & `{{ $law->fine }}` to add up and then display in `#punishment` `<input>`

Thanks for looking!

Comment: This would also be make a good `Livewire` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do some thing like this.

**Update `<option>` tag to this**

```
<option data-fine="{{$law['fine']}}" data-months="{{$law['months']}}" value="{{ $law['name'] }} {{ $law['fine'] }} {{ $law['months'] }}">Offence: {{ $law['name'] }} </option>
```

**and you can get `data` attribute of the selected `<option>` tag in your script like this.**

```
`$("#lawspicker").change(function() {
  var fine = $(this).find(':selected').data('fine');
  let months = $(this).find(':selected').data('months');
  $("#punishment").val(parseInt(fine+months));
});`
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I get this error https://flareapp.io/share/47qeXoG7?owner_token=ywtG5O0bt5jaX6m2a3Y5U55MyrHRtZyL

Comment: I had to return ```{{$law['fine']}}``` to ```{{ $law->fine }}``` otherwise it get the error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" After doing that, the error goes away but still nothing happens when things are selected.

Comment: Yes,  as I just tested it with custom array, you can just replace array with object type and it will work fine for you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to replace your `select` element with `checkbox`es personally.

An example below using `jquery` to calculate the `fine` and `months` when a button is clicked but could be an event of your choosing. I stripped it back from your example so it was easier to see what is going on.

**Checkbox example**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Select Offences</h4>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="laws[]" id="law-a" data-fine="100" data-months="12" class="custom-control-input offence">
            <label for="law-a" class="custom-control-label">Law A</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="laws[]" id="law-b" data-fine="999" data-months="6.5" class="custom-control-input offence">
            <label for="law-b" class="custom-control-label">Law B</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="laws[]" id="law-c" data-fine="123.5" data-months="8" class="custom-control-input offence">
            <label for="law-c" class="custom-control-label">Law C</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="punishment">Punishment</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="punishment" name="punishment" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then some `javascript` (`jquery`)

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    let fine = 0;
    let months = 0;
    $(".offence").each(function(index, obj) {
      if (obj.checked) {
        fine += parseFloat($(obj).data("fine"));
        months += parseFloat($(obj).data("months"));
      }
    })
    $("#punishment").val("Fine: "+ fine + " Months: " + months);
  })
});
```

When you click `submit`, the javascript will loop through each element with the `offence` class and then read the value of the `data-fine` and calculate the totals.

An example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dbtas60w/

**Multiselect example**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Select Offences</h4>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <select class="selectpicker" id="lawspicker" name="laws[]" multiple>
            <option data-fine="100" data-months="12">Law A</option>
            <option data-fine="999" data-months="6.5">Law B</option>
            <option data-fine="123.5" data-months="8">Law C</option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="punishment">Punishment</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="punishment" name="punishment" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    let fine = 0;
    let months = 0;
    $("#lawspicker>option").each(function(index, obj) {
      if (obj.selected) {
        fine += parseFloat($(obj).data("fine"));
        months += parseFloat($(obj).data("months"));
      }
    })
    $("#punishment").val("Fine: "+ fine + " Months: " + months);
  })
});
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dbtas60w/1/

Comment: I can see where you're coming from on this one and thank you but that would mean circa 160 checkboxes so not really a suitable usecase for this project. Thank you though.

Comment: @IanProbets - Yikes, I see how that could be an issue. I have added an example using the `select` element with the `multiple` attribute. Functions pretty much the same way, just some slightly different `javascript`.

Comment: ikr! Sure, I'm open to anything suggestions as I have still not solved this! Appreciate it

Comment: I tried your multiselect method that you kindly added.

Comment: I modified some portions to try and grab the data I need. `fine += parseFloat($(obj).data("{{ $law->fine }}"));
          months += parseFloat($(obj).data("{{ $law->months }}"));` When I hit calculate, I get NaN

Comment: @unflix, I sorted it. Thank you!